# Grails 3 and Java 8 time support

Tags: grails, grails-orm, java-time, grails-3.0

In grails 3 application, I see that new java.time classes are persisted to database. Dynamic queries and create criteria works. However, I am wondering if there is some better way how to store these time data to database. When I look to database I see some binary data, it seems it just serialize the time objects.

Is there any similar plugin as joda-time-plugin or is there any way how to configure database mapping for java.time classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit**: Grails 3.1.1 has hibernate 5 so this is not an issue anymore...

Grails

I finally found a solution. First of all hibernate 5 implements persistent for java 8 time (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844). However, grails 3 uses hibernate 4 and I haven't found any plans to upgrade hibernate in grails.

There is an implementation for java 8 time hibernate user types (jadira extended package) which can be used similarly as in joda time plugin (see http://gpc.github.io/joda-time/guide/persistence.html). For me only version 3.1.0.GA and lower worked.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.extended:3.1.0.GA"
}
```

application.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threeten.PersistentInstantAsMillisLong, class: java.time.Instant
}
```