# How do I display local time with Groovy's .format() method?

Tags: date, groovy, format

I have a set of dates that were saved to the database with the following code (which I can't change):

```
Date date = new Date()
save(date)
```

Is there no clean way in groovy to reformat and display the date in the user's local time zone? Such as ...

```
dateCreated.format('h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy', Locale.US)
```

Is nothing like that built into Groovy? Is the only solution?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String date = dateCreated.format('h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy')
def fmt = new SimpleDateFormat('h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy', Locale.US);
Date local_time = fmt.parse(date);
String formatted_local = local_time.format('h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy')
formatted_local
```

Groovy Date Documentation: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)

Reference: [How to parse month full form string using DateFormat in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219139/how-to-parse-month-full-form-string-using-dateformat-in-java)

Comment: I don't follow your question, but if you think it can be done in Java, then it can also be done in Groovy as that Java snippet is valid Groovy. I'd use `Date.parse('h:mm a MMMM dd, yyyy', '6:31 PM June 27, 2007')`

Comment: Is there a more universal approach? i.e. let's say the date is stored with format 'MM-d-yyyy-h-mm-s' in the database, how do I use Date.parse to print the date in the new format?

Comment: You have dates saved as strings in a database?

Comment: For this project they're stored with the Date SQL type (plugged into Grails), but I'm asking generically. First, line of my gross solution turns them into strings because that's what simpleDateFormat takes as input. It's gross which is why the question.

Comment: @DevonLuongo, have you got chance to look at the solution provided and try that?

Comment: @Rao, thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @DevonLuongo, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty simple in Groovy.

Assume, date is saved using below statement

```
def date = new Date()
println date
```

**Output**

```
Sun Apr 16 11:10:14 UTC 2017
```

If you need to convert it to specific time zone with specific date time format, just use below statement

```
println date.format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
```

**Would display output:**

```
2017/04/16 16:40
```

NOTE: source is in `UTC` format and converted the existing date to `IST` format.

In case if you need date object (not string as mentioned in the above), use below:

```
def date = new Date()
def dtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
def dt = date.format(dtFormat, TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
assert dt instanceof String

def newDate = Date.parse(dtFormat, dt)
assert newDate instanceof Date
```

You may quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5168586796564480)</kbd>

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse ( 
    "Mon Apr 03 16:49:56 PDT 2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.US ) 
)
```

## Syntax

Sorry, I don’t know Groovy syntax, so this is in Java syntax.

## `java.util.Date::toString`

Are you saying that values were saved to your database as a textual data type by calling [`java.util.Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--)?

So now you need to parse the strings in the default format used by [`java.util.Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) such as `Mon Apr 03 16:49:56 PDT 2017` to get back to a date-time object.

Firstly, you must already know that was a dreadful way to store a date-time value. That format assumes English, and lops off any fractional second. That format is difficult to read by humans, and difficult to parse by machines. It uses the 3-4 letter abbreviations of pseudo time zones like `PDT` or `IST` which are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique(!). [Proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

## ISO 8601

Instead, when serializing date-time values, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Know that `java.util.Date` is one of the troublesome poorly-designed confusing old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Avoid the legacy classes, use java.time instead.

## Using java.time

The `DateTimeFormatter` class parses strings. We must define a formatting pattern to match the output of `Date::toString`.

```
String input = "Mon Apr 03 16:49:56 PDT 2017" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.US ) ;
```

Now we can parse that string as a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input, f ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-04-03T16:49:56-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Generally the best practice for serializing date-time values for data storage and exchange is to keep the value in UTC and then make a string in standard ISO 8601 format. The convention for UTC in ISO 8601 is to append a `Z`, short for `Zulu` and meaning UTC.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-04-03T23:49:56Z

## JDBC

Your Question and Comments are not clear. If your values are stored in a database using proper date-time types, then there is no need to mess about with strings as discussed above. If properly stored, you should be letting your JDBC driver do the work of fetching data in and out of the database while converting as necessary.

Drivers compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later can directly use the java.time types via `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I'll try this out next time. Groovy/Grails seems to default to Java.util.Date so I assumed it was standard. Java.time looks much better though.

Comment: @DevonLuongo Comparing java.time to the legacy classes is like comparing [Yugo cars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugo) to Honda cars – really no comparison at all.

Comment: Update: Unfortunately, Grails has compatibility issues with Java.time. A temporary solution has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974704/grails-3-and-java-8-time-support

Comment: The DateTimeFormatter is not existing. Must be imported: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter